# Cohabitation of RcppArmadillo and RcppParallel

Tags: rcpp

The following toy example for `parallelFor` works fine (`f2` is the parallelized version of `f1`):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <iostream>
#define vector NumericVector

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;


// compute values i/i+1 for i = 0 to n-1
// [[Rcpp::export]]
vector f1(int n) {
  vector x(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) x[i] = (double) i/ (i+1);
  return x;
}

struct mytry : public Worker {
  vector output;

  mytry(vector out) : output(out) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    for(int i = begin; i < end; i++) output[i] = (double) i/ (i+1);
  }

};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vector f2(int n) {
  vector x(n);
  mytry A(x);
  parallelFor(0, n, A);
  return x;
}
```

However, if I replace `#define vector NumericVector` by `#define vector arma::vec` this doesn’t work any more. The codes compiles and run, `f1` is ok, but the vector returned by `f2` just contains uninitialized values.

Many thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: Should the `arma::vec` be a reference member of the class? (This works for the `Rcpp` case as R's vectors are just proxy objects over pointers, so you're still getting access to the same objet)

Comment: @KevinUshey It's ok, two well-placed `&` and it runs: Precisely, replace `vector output;` by `vector & output;` and `mytry(vector out) : output(out) {}` by `mytry(vector & out) : output(out) {}`. Will you formulate your comment as an answer? I be glad to accept it. As I am unlikely to be the only noob meeting this problem one day, I think it is worth it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here -- your class should be taking the vector by reference, rather than by value.

This is because, when using `RcppParallel`, you typically pre-allocate memory for an object somewhere, then fill that object -- so the parallel workers should be taking a reference to that object you want to fill.

So your worker should look like (as you noted):

```
struct mytry : public Worker {
  vector& output;

  mytry(vector& out) : output(out) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    for(int i = begin; i < end; i++) output[i] = (double) i/ (i+1);
  }
```

Note that this works (perhaps surprisingly) for Rcpp vectors because they already are just 'proxy' objects -- just objects encapsulating a **pointer to data**. When you pass an Rcpp vector by value, you copy the pointer (not the underlying data!) plus some extra vector bits (e.g. the length of the vector) -- so the 'copy' retains a reference to the same data structure.

When you use a more 'classical' vector, e.g. the `arma::vec` or `std::vector`, when passing that by value to the worker you really are copying a whole new vector to the class, then filling that (temporary, copied) vector -- so the original vector never actually gets filled.